# Display highchart and swiftDataTable in two different cells of a collectionView

Tags: swift, highcharts, uiview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'am trying to display for each report the associated chart(using HighChart) in a first collectionViewCell and when you swipe to the right you get the associated dataTable(i Use SwiftDataTables) in the second collectionViewCell.The issue that i have been facing these recent three days is that i can't display neither one of them in the collectionviewCell using

`func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {}`

here is my code:

1- collectionView and customCell instance :

```
lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.backgroundColor = .white
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.delegate = self
        cv.isPagingEnabled = true

        return cv
    }()

var pages: [Page] = []
```

2-Custom CollectionViewCell : PageCell

```
import UIKit
import Highcharts
import SwiftDataTables
import ChameleonFramework

class PageCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var imageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        iv.backgroundColor = .yellow
        iv.image = UIImage(named: "background_2")
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        return iv
    }()

    var pageView: UIView= {
        let pv = UIView()
        pv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        pv.clipsToBounds = true

        return pv
    }()


    var page: Page? {
        didSet {
           // print(page?.mainView)

            guard let unwrappedPage = page else {
                return
            }
            //imageView.image = UIImage(named: unwrappedPage.image)//unwrappedPage.image

            pageView = unwrappedPage.mainView
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: unwrappedPage.image)

            print("imageView.image: ", imageView.image)
            print("PageViewContent: ", pageView)
            print("unwrappedPage.mainView: ", unwrappedPage.mainView)
        }
    }


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews() {

         addSubview(imageView)
         imageView.anchorWithConstantsToTop(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: 70, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 100, rightConstant: 0)



        addSubview(pageView)
        pageView.anchorWithConstantsToTop(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: 70, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 100, rightConstant: 0)


        //imageView.frame = CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.origin.x, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.origin.y+70, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height-100)



    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

3- Struct for the custom Cell : Page

```
import Foundation

struct Page {
    let mainView: UIView
    let image: String
}
```

2 - Adding the collectionView to the View + setting the constrains

```
 //TODO: collectionView Config
  self.view.addSubview(self.collectionView)
  self.collectionView.anchorToTop(top: self.view.topAnchor, left: 
  self.view.leftAnchor, bottom: self.view.bottomAnchor, right: 
  self.view.rightAnchor)
  self.collectionView.register(PageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
 self.pages = {
          let firstPage = Page(mainView: self.chartView, image: "background_2")
          let secondPage = Page(mainView: self.chartView, image: "background_2")
           return [firstPage, secondPage]
                    }()
```

3-CollectionView Methods :

```
    //MARK: - UICollectionViewController Extension
extension SecondViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {



    //TODO: numberOfItemsInSection method
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return pages.count
    }


    //TODO: cellForItemAt method
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! PageCell

        let page = pages[indexPath.item]

        cell.page = page

        return cell
    }

    //TODO: collectionViewLayout method

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
    }


    //TODO: scrollViewWillEndDragging method
    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

        let x = targetContentOffset.pointee.x

        pageControl.currentPage = Int(x / view.frame.width)


    }


}
```

Knowing that for the imageView case it works perfectly i get each image in the associated cell but for the views(chatyView and the datatable) it's a blank space unless i add them just after the colection view using :

```
self.collectionView.addSubview(self.chartView)

self.chartView.anchorWithConstantsToTop(top: self.view.topAnchor, left: self.view.leftAnchor, bottom: self.view.bottomAnchor, right: self.view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 50, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 20, rightConstant: 0)  


self.collectionView.addSubview(self.dataTable) 

self.dataTable.anchorWithConstantsToTop(top: self.view.topAnchor, left: self.view.leftAnchor, bottom: self.view.bottomAnchor, right: self.view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 70, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 20, rightConstant: 0)
```

it's the only case where it works but it doesn't satisfied my need beacause they are displayied on on the top of the other in each cell :/ .

what i've tried so far but didn't work with for me :

- Instead of using PageCell as custom cell i've used UICollectionViewCell, and i've created a UIView array by using append i added the views and tried to assign them to the appropriate cell using itemForCellAtIndexpath Method.Didn't Work.
- Instead of cell = page[indexPath.item] i've used cell.contanView.addSubView().didn't get lucky with that either.
- Also tried to use place of an Arrray of UIView to use the specefic type such as HiChartView/SwiftDatable. but didn't work.

What i found bizarre is that it worked perfectly with UIImageView but not with the chart or dataTable unless i'm adding them right after the collectionView config .

Thanks in advance (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by removing :

`self.dataTable.anchorWithConstantsToTop(top: self.view.topAnchor, left: self.view.leftAnchor, bottom: self.view.bottomAnchor, right: self.view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 70, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 20, rightConstant: 0)`

and instead adding :

```
self.dataTable.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.origin.x, y: self.frame.origin.y, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
```

and same for the chartView.